# How can I transport animals over long distances?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Apart from holding the food that the animal like and walking, is it possible to transport animals over long distances?

I'm thinking about what happens if I find a mushroom biome on a boat trip with Mooshrooms; would I be able to transport them home?

Comment: Minecarts are your friend

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to 1.4, you can just build a nether portal and transport them that way! You'll still be holding the food and walking (or building a minecart track), but the distance is 8 times shorter.

Comment: Ah, so they would follow me through the portal and then I can use the space dilation effect to shorten the journey home. Good idea! Although I imagine the walk could be dangerous.

Comment: @sync: Indeed could, but you can always build a tunnel or minecart track, and a journey in the overworld can be quite dangerous aswell, with all the ravines, cliffs and surface lava pools. :)

Answer (score 8):

You could build a minecart track and put them in carts.

Comment: Yeah this one had occurred to me but seemed unrealistic if it was a really long distance. Wish there was a boat equivalent! Thanks

Comment: I had to build a 2K long underground track to get villagers to where I wanted in my world.  That sucked....  But, took less time than I thought, Diamond Efficiency IV pickaxes are *fast*!

Comment: Efficiency V is even faster! But against dirt it sometimes is *too* fast and leaves ghost blocks for me...